# Sort Map results

Tags: apex, class, map

I have a map which I want to sort the results in ASC order

Let's say that yearToDate is holding the below result

The result I have in yearToDate is

```
yearToDate::{Year 1=2023-09-15 00:00:00, Year 2=2024-03-15 00:00:00}
yearToDate = new Map<String, Decimal>();
```

and I am running the result to build another Map data

```
        yearToDate = new Map<String, Date> ();
        dateToDecimal = new Map<String, Decimal> ();
        for (String eKey : yearToDate.keySet()) {
        String key = 'Total ' + getMonthName(yearToDate.get(eKey)) + ' ' + yearToDate.get(eKey).year();
        dateToDecimal.put(key, yearToSum.get(eKey));
    }


    public static String getMonthName(Date value)
{
    return Datetime.newInstance(value, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).format('MMMM');
}
```

In the above example, I am getting the result as

```
dateToDecimal::{Total March 2024=12000.00, Total September 2023=6265.67}
```

The expected result would be like

```
dateToDecimal::{Total September 2023=6265.67, Total March 2024=12000.00}
```

I don't see any examples as well to sort this result in the correct order. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If possible please share the full code.

Comment: I added the required code in my question. To say it simple, yearToDate is something I am trying to show it in different format. If you check the yearToDate, it is 2023-09-15. All I am doing it showing it as Total September 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Maps and Sets in Apex have a deterministic order, which means that the order you put elements in them is the order they are iterated over.

For example:

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new Map<String, String>();
testMap.put('Stack', 'Exchange');
testMap.put('Sales', 'Force');
for(String key : testMap.keySet()){
    //'Stack' will always come before 'Sales'
}
```

So in your example, as long as the elements are in the right order in your first `Map`, when you iterate over the keys, they will stay in that order. And they will be in that order in your new `Map`.